# How to use click and waitForNavigation?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const cookies_json_file = process.argv[2];
const url = process.argv[3];
const timeout = parseInt(process.argv[4], 10);

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const cookiesString = await fs.readFile(cookies_json_file);
    const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
    await page.setCookie.apply(page, cookies);
    try {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: timeout });
        const content = await page.content();
        page.on('response', async response => {
            if(response.url().startsWith('https://www.genecards.org/gene/api/data/Enhancers?geneSymbol=')) {
                response.buffer().then(function(data) {
                    fs.writeFile('/dev/stdout', data);
                });
            }
        });

        const linkHandlers = await page.$x('//div[@data-ga-category = "GeneHancer"]//a[@data-role = "show-all"]');
        if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
            await Promise.all([
                linkHandlers[0].click()
                , page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: timeout})
            ]);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Link not found");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

I have the above `main.js`.

```
$ ./main.js cookies.json 'https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=BSCL2' 30000
```

When I run using the above command, I got this error. Does anybody know how to fix the error? Thanks.

````
TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:649:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
    at main.js:33:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5) {
  name: 'TimeoutError'
}
```
````

Answer (score -1):

You will need to disable timeout by setting the timeout parameter to 0. The default is 30 seconds (which you are also passing as a command line argument from your example), so this is behaving as expected and throwing an exception because the timeout exceeded the default or user supplied value of 30000 milliseconds.

```
 page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0})
```

You can also pass the parameter from the command line as an argument, which is preferable so as not to hard-code the value:

```
$ ./main.js cookies.json 'https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=BSCL2' 0
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. When I set timeout 0, it still hangs there but forever. What it should behave is terminate immediately after print the content of `https://www.genecards.org/gene/api/data/Enhancers?geneSymbol=BSCL2`

Comment: If it hangs forever then you have successfully disabled timeout. Most likely the action you are waiting at that endpoint never completes. Try to log the output of that api call.

Comment: I am still new with puppeteer. I am not sure how to do it. Would you please show me a complete example? Also, I try to add `process.exit(0);` after `fs.writeFile('/dev/stdout', data);`, but the program won't terminate later. Is there something along this line to terminate the program once the content of data is printed? Thanks.